# Poker Combinations: How many ways can you get 4 of the same suit in a hand of 5 cards?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The homework question is: in how many ways can we get exactly 4 cards of the same suit in a hand of 5 cards? (Order does not matter.)

Here is what I have: we need to pick two different suits, decide which suit will have 4 cards and which will have 1, pick 4 ranks for one suit, pick 1 for the other. That is, $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{13}{4}\binom{13}{1}$$

Does this seem correct? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "exactly four of the same suit" or just "four of the same suit"? In other words is "Ad2d3d4d5d" a valid combination?

Comment: No, I mean exactly four of the same suit. (One of the cards would have to be of a different suit.)

Comment: When you say "in how many ways", do you just mean "how many different poker hands have this" or do you mean that whether the off-suit card is the first or third card in the hand matters?

Comment: Order does not matter. I just mean "how many different poker hands have this"

Comment: It looks entirely reasonable to me! If you figure is correct, it should happen in about 4.29% of randomly drawn hands.

Comment: I wrote a tiny program testing this figure, but I get around $5900$ successes in $100000$ hands. Maybe my program has a flaw in it? Here is a [link](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user40_Q3ZDWgVz3SfP3qD_0.py) to it.

Comment: @String Hey, thanks for your help! I'm not great at coding, but I think the problem is that each time you're running the iteration "for j in range(5):", you can pick the same number again. It would be as though you picked 2H, and then replaced it, and then you pick from 52 cards again. If there was a way you chose 2H and left it out of the range for the next iteration, then I think you'd get around 42900 success.

Comment: @String Like I said, I'm pretty awful at this! But if you could make something like [this](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user40_OHYN0eK8CU_0.py) work, I think that would give the right answer!

Comment: @Sai: You are absolutely correct. [Here is a new version that works](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user40_1PvqbseENk_0.py). It appears to be consistent with around $429$ successes in $10000$ trials.

Comment: The other program I wrote should have probability $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{1}\cdot 4^{-5}\approx 5.859\%$$ so that checks out too :o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Here is an alternate method:  Select one of the four suits, four of the thirteen cards from that suit, and one of the $39$ cards that is not of that suit, which yields 
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{13}{4}\binom{39}{1}$$